# How can I create a wx.Frame without a parent?

Tags: python, window, wxpython

When I try to make a new frame with `wx.Frame(False)`, I get this error, passed down through the callstack:

```
TypeError: in method 'new_Frame', expected argument 1 of type 'wxWindow *'
```

I get that the argument should be the parent window, but at least in C++ you can pass a null pointer if you don't want the window to have a parent.

**How can I create a wx.Frame without a parent?**

Comment: Try using `None` instead of `False`.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass `None`. As seen in this example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# simple.py

import wx

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'simple.py')
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can pass `None`. This is the normal way and the way that you'll see done in most examples. I prefer to show an example of a frame class:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title='Test')
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You can also use Python's `super` when defining your subclass with wxPython:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame(parent=None, title='Test')
    app.MainLoop()
```